# Free NHibernate helper tools?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-3.5, code-generation

Are there any free tools to help simplify working with an NHibernate project in .NET 3.5?  Primarily, I'm looking for some kind of code and config file generator to automate some of the more tedious parts of working with NHibernate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Fluent-NHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/) presents an alternative way of writing your mapping, that for example is more refactor friendly than the standard XML approach.

Example:

```
public CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
  public CustomerMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.Credit);
    HasMany<Product>(x => x.Products)
      .AsBag();
    Component<Address>(x => x.Address, m =>  
    {  
        m.Map(x => x.AddressLine1);  
        m.Map(x => x.AddressLine2);  
        m.Map(x => x.CityName);  
        m.Map(x => x.CountryName);  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[NHibernate Query Analyzer](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/06/02/NHibernate-Query-Analyzer-for-NHibernate-1.2-GA.aspx) is a must for constructing queries. It's not for configuration, I know, but a must when trying to get your head around HQL.

Comment: NQA does appear to have support for configuration specifically for editing mapping files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528707/hibernate-nhibernate-mapping-file-editor/739835#739835

Comment: Can you use NHibernate Query Analyzer with Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 4):

Keep an eye out for Oren (Ayende)'s NHhibernate Profiler:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/11/04/nh-prof-a-guided-tour.aspx

It is not yet released but it looks very promising.

Answer (score 3):

[ActiveWriter](http://altinoren.com/activewriter/) is a plugin to Visual Studio that generates some files for NHibernate, but I haven't had a chance to dig into it yet.

Answer (score 3):

[MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/Home/tabid/36/Default.aspx) has some [nHibernate tempates](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/templatelibrary/default.aspx) for code generation.

There used to be some for the free version of Code-Smith too, but I don't think they have been updated in a while.

Answer (score 3):

What about an [active record implementation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) with attribute-based definition on top of nhibernate?

Answer (score 3):

David Hayden has put together [T4 Templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) that generate sample Fluent NHibernate Mapping Classes.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/12/14/t4-templates-for-fluent-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

what about NConstruct Lite, a small powerfull tool to generating mapping files and Entities...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [dPulpo](http://www.dpulpo.com), a datalayer generation tool that generates NHibernate mapping files, C# entity classes and your SQL database.  There is a Visual Studio plugin and it's currently in beta and free for download.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of LLBLGen is able to generate sample Fluent NHibernate Mapping Classes and entities.