# Hibernate/NHibernate mapping file editor

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm looking for an editor that has the help from

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/mapping.html

built in, and allows simple editing of the XML files in a GUI fashion. I realise there's CodeSmith and MyGeneration, but from what I remember these only go one way, and don't allow editing existing HBM files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably worth taking a look at the NHibernate Query Analyzer by Oren Eini. 
Primarily used to analyze HQL queries it also has a fairly useful HBM editor:

[NHibernate Query Analyzer Screenshot http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5617/nhqa.gif](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5617/nhqa.gif)

Old Project Page (with flash demo): http://ayende.com/projects/nhibernate-query-analyzer.aspx

New Project Page: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/NHibernateQueryAnalyzer

This will allow editing for HBM files and will show all of the available attributes for each mapping node.

Given that you *can* download the source code it wouldn't be that trivial to add the inline help.

Comment: This looks the most promising, except it gets an exception when loading "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.35.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Comment: Try downloading and installing the correct version from here:http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=132486&package_id=145568

Comment: I downloaded + recompiled and go it working. I think this is probably the closest to the answer I'll get so I'll give you the tick :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is an editor for Hibernate/NHibernate mapping files that has context-sensitive help. If you are a .NET developer (using NHibernate and Visual Studio .NET) you can edit the mappings with IntelliSense by registering a schema document: see [Using NHibernate with Visual Studio .NET](http://www.hibernate.org/366.html) for instructions.

Another option to consider is using the [NHibernate's Fluent API](http://fluentnhibernate.org/). This replaces mapping files with strongly-typed C# code.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option with Visual Studio. If you have Resharper you can download the plug-in for NHibernate mapping files. This solution has worked out perfectly for me. You can read more about the plug in here: http://nhplugin.lieser-online.de/. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ActiveWriter to generate the mappings? You can always edit them afterwards. AW generates the model / mapping for both NHibernate and ActiveRecord. The editor runs WITHIN Visual Studio.NET and you can do drag-drop via server explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I've come across is is IDEA's [Hibernate/JPA editor](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/java_hibernate.html). IDEA is not free, however.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Hibernate's own Eclipse plug-in named *Hibernate Tools for Eclipse and Ant*?

http://www.hibernate.org/255.html

Even if you dont have expirience with Eclipse and its add-ons it should be fairly straightforward to install and use their addon:

Just download it, unzip it into the eclipse directory, and fire up the IDE.
What you need to do next is to open up the Hibernate perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VisualStudio and the schema (nhibernate-mapping.xsd) to activate the intellisense.
The plug-in for R# is useful to check the mapping with the class.