# Mapping files generation with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i m new to nhibenate and i really find it painful to write the entire mapping files is there a tool or a vs addin that helps you do the mapping ?

thx for your time :)

Comment: Duplicate. This question is already asked a few times. Try search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nhibernate+generate+mapping

Comment: Scrolling down the search results you will find links like these and probably more.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812510/how-can-i-generate-nhibernate-mapping-files-and-db-constructs-from-my-domain-logi

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528707/hibernate-nhibernate-mapping-file-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an existing database that you want to map you can use the open source tool [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/) to create both mapping files and the domain objects from the database. In this [screencast](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/10/summer-of-nhibernate-session-08-techniques-for-effective-database-driven-modeling-is-now-available/) you can see how this can be done.

You can also use [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/), however this is a commercial tool. This [screencast](http://community.codesmithtools.com/blogs/videotutorials/archive/2008/11/04/using-codesmith-nhibernate-templates.aspx) shows the use of this tool with NHibernate.

If you write the XML yourself, make sure that you have intellisense in VS. This [blog](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/EnablingIntellisenseForNHibernate.aspx) describes how this is done.

If it is just the XML you don't like, check out http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org where you do the mapping with C# code. Check out [this blog post](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/05/24/Mapping-a-Twitter-like-domain-with-Fluent-NHibernate.aspx) (mine) for an example.

You can also do the mapping with Attributes, but there seems to be not to many examples of this.

You can also check out [Caste ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html), which "*is built on top of NHibernate, but its attribute-based mapping free the developer of writing XML for database-to-object mapping, which is needed when using NHibernate directly*". Here are some [tutorials](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/04/28/NHibernateCastleActiveRecordTutorialUninitiated.aspx) on this.