# Tools to convert database tables to C# classes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, class, mapping

Is there any free tool or plug-in for Visual Studio to convert the SQL tables to entity, model, facade and DAO classes? I am working on SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2008 and C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=VS.90).aspx) (although the future of LINQ to SQL is a bit vague)?

If you were using Visual Studio 2010 you'd get [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) tooling in the box.

There's also NHibernate which has a variety of free tooling:

> [Free NHibernate helper tools? (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278046/free-nhibernate-helper-tools)

Answer (score 4):

Try using [SQLMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) from Microsoft. The files aren't pretty, but they work and also provide LINQ functionality. It's also free :)

I've used it first hand, and it works very well. The beauty of it is, it generates everything from one command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This tool helps to create only the entity class.. but I want to generate 4 types of classes.. Model, DAO, entity and Facade..

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/exploring-linq,-sqlmetal-and-sqltac/    <---   Have a flick through that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) is free.  It's a pretty common tool for ORP.  All you have to do is write some XML to map class fields to tables and you're set.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET

I forgot to mention, another reason I like NHibernate is that is completely abstracts away the specific type of relational system you are connecting to, thus making your code more portable.  I might be wrong, but I always thought that LINQ was very tightly coupled with SQL Server (M$ love lock-in) -- NHibernate gives you freedom from this in case at some point your back-end relational system is no longer SQL Server.

Comment: you can also use Fluent NHibernate to eliminate the need to write any xml files.  fluentnhibernate.org/

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework may be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

[Codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator)?

Answer (score 0):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) does what you ask.  It has ActiveRecord and Repository style implementations, for your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You should give Subsonic a try. NHibernate is probably one the mature ORMs. If you are a part of an organization, you might have some of the heavy duty and expensive ORMs like the [Telerik OpenAccess](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) or [DevExpress XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/). My first ORM was [Adapdev Codus](http://codus.software.informer.com/). Unfortunately, I have no idea why the developer [hit the high road](http://forums.asp.net/t/1406970.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

First, I would seriously consider using an industry standard ORM solution (Linq2SQL, EntityFramework, NHibernate, LLBL).  If you still want to roll your own, I found some benefit in reading over the  [LinqToSQL](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/19/linq-to-sql-templates-updated-now-on-codeplex) templates themselves and modifying the code to do what I needed with t4.